# headers already sent by Divi

Tags: php, wordpress, divi-theme

```
<?php
    if(is_user_logged_in()){
        //do something
    }else{
        wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
        exit;
    }
?>
```

So I try to do that, but get a header already sent error by Divi.

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /public_html/wp-content/themes/Divi/header.php:1)
>   in /public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1265

Is this a common error, any ideas to fix that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the page showing content before the PHP script is released. This can be a lot of things, if there's HTML being shown before the script I think it can do this. I've seen it happen before with trailing whitespace after closing a php tag too.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense the Divi menu is shown.
Do you also know a other way to check if the user is logged in and if not redirect the user to the login page?

Comment: You can add to your child theme: <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>

<a href="linktologgedinuserpage">add a title</a>

<?php else:  ?>

<a href="<?php echo wp_login_url(); ?>">Log In</a>

<?php endif; ?>